# Why The Returned Data Type of findAll Method Are Different Between CrudRepository And JpaRepositiory?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

The returned data types of findAll method are Iterable and List for CrudRepository and JpaRespository. And JpaRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository which extends CrudRepository. I am wondering why the returned data type are different. Any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CrudRepository` is defined in `spring-data-commons` which is used by all the Spring Data modules.
The idea behind using `Iterable` was to allow for stores to not materialise the full result when the method returns.

Queries in JPA return `List` instances and therefore there is no reason not to return `List` instances.

In practice no module returns a non-collection `Iterable` and the team just discussed that we might change the return type to `Collection` in the not too far future.